# Deployement of Play! web app with Nginx

Tags: nginx, playframework-2.0, web-deployment

I'm trying to do some deploy on my webb app project with Play! and Nginx.

I followed the guide on Play! web site but it dosen't work. Sombody get to make it works?
Wich are the differences?

PS: My web app work, if I it localhost:9000 I get the page and if I hit only localhost I get the welcome message from Nginx, but I can't make them work together.

Thanks

Comment: does putting "localhost:9000" on your browser make the app work ?

Comment: is your default port 80? or did you change it to 90?

Comment: Yes, it works with "localhost:9000", and yes, I changed to 9000.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say you only need to do a proxy pass in nginx, replace the `example.com` with your website name.

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;
}
```

if you don't want to create a separate server block,  you can use a location block

```
location /webapp {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:9000;
}
```

This way it would work by using `http://localhost/webapp`

Comment: Thanks, but I'm trying to deploying it locally, and this doesn't seem to works.

Comment: can you show me your nginx conf after adding the location block `/webapp` ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have changed the default port to 9000. Only using `localhost/projectname` is going through port 80. In order to do it that way you should change your default port to port 80.

Comment: Yes, but I have to change it in the Nginx.conf file or using Play?

Comment: if you change to port 80 that would conflict with nginx, because nginx is already listening to port 80, if you decide to use this method you need to shutdown nginx totally.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my nginx configuration:

```
upstream play_app {
    server 0.0.0.0:9000;
}

server {
    listen      7000;
    location    / {
        proxy_pass      http://play_app;
    }
}
```

And then you just need to visit your website via: IP:7000